# Cannot access first page header (python-docx)

Tags: python, python-docx

I have recently wrote python code to replace a word in MS office via python-docx. The code is working good for a couple of week. I can access through all the header in all page with this code below;

```
sections = doc.sections
for z in range (0, len(sections)):
    header_section = doc.sections[z]
    header = header_section.header
    header_text = header.paragraphs[0]
```

However a fews days ago I found some issue. The code seem not to work with first page of the document (but still work in the later page). I have try to figure out why the code just stop working and it seem that it is something about different first page setting of the document (I try create a new document without different first page and it work just fine). Can anyone please kindly suggest what cause my code to stop working, so I could try to find the way to rewrote the code (Any MS Office update that may effect the code?). And if you have any idea how to access the header in the document with different first page setting, please kindly share. Thank in advance.

Comment: Your question is underqualified and over specific. Under qualified in providing enough information to replicate the issue and over specified by providing too much questions at the same time.

Comment: You may do not want to access `header.paragraphs[0]` if there is no element in it. So you have to check that first

Comment: Please accept my apology, I am quite new to the community.

Answer (score 3):

A section can have up to three headers (and three footers). These are the first-page header, odd-page header, and default-header. Most sections have only the default header, but if the first-page header is defined, it is used for the first page only. This is because the first page of a chapter, say, would typically not have a header or may have a different header than the "running" header through the rest of the chapter or other section.

So look to see whether you have a first-page header or odd-page header defined; that could explain the behavior you're seeing. See these pages in the documentation for more:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#id1
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/hdrftr.html

Comment: Thank you sir. I can now access the first page header. :)

Comment: @YootthachaiK welcome to StackOverflow. Don't neglect to accept the answer to your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. This acknowledges the respondent for taking the time to write an answer and also builds your own reputation.

Comment: I have click the accept button, but seem that I just very new to stackoverflow, so they just record the accept, but does not show on the mark.

Answer (score 0):

This mystified me for a while, thanks for the tip to read the docs more closely. For those looking for a copy/paste, here's what I did:

```
def get_headers_and_footers(doc: Document):
    header_txt = set()
    for section in doc.sections:
        for paragraph in section.header.paragraphs:
            header_txt.add(paragraph.text)
        for paragraph in section.first_page_header.paragraphs:
            header_txt.add(paragraph.text)
        for paragraph in section.even_page_header.paragraphs:
            header_txt.add(paragraph.text)

    footer_txt = set()
    for section in doc.sections:
        for paragraph in section.header.paragraphs:
            footer_txt.add(paragraph.text)
        for paragraph in section.first_page_header.paragraphs:
            footer_txt.add(paragraph.text)
        for paragraph in section.even_page_header.paragraphs:
            footer_txt.add(paragraph.text)
    
    return list(header_txt), list(footer_txt)
```